# Rails 3 - Devise Gem - How to Manage Users through CRUD interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Devise gem is used for authentication.  I need to have a user index and show view.  Found this how to at the devise wiki, however played around, can not make it work.

[Devise - How To: Manage users through a CRUD interface](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface)

Method 1: Remember to remove the :registerable module from the Devise model (in my case it was the User model) Make sure to put your map.resources :users below the map.devise_for :users route (devise_for :users and resources :users for Rails 3).

Method 2: devise_for :users, :path_prefix => ‘d’ resources :users to isolate the devise logic from your crud user controlle

My question:
1. if you remove registerable in the model, then how does devise work for user?
2. If you done this, can you provide a sample?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By placing the appropriate new.html.erb, edit.html.erb, _form.html.erb etc files in the User Views folder, adding/editing/deleting Users should work no differently as any other CRUD, as Devise's User is another model like any. I won't post the new or edit erbs (simple enough, and a scaffold can show you the rest), but an example of my User _form.html.erb...

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= render :partial => 'shared/errors', :locals => { :content => @user } %>

   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
   </div>   

   <div class="field">  
      <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
      <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
   </div>

   <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
   </div>

<% end %>
```

In mine, I think I left :registerable in and I'm still able to administer and update users via the CRUD. If you leave it out, then users can't register themselves, but you can still add and edit users yourself (would protect the Users controller with load_and_authorize_resource to keep regular users out, of course).

Comment: thanks for your help.  Let me understand what you are suggesting:  I generated user model using - rails g devise User, and you suggest do: rails g controller Users index new show edit, right???

Comment: I have to admit that I did it slightly differently where I have two user controllers, one regular users_controllers.rb where registered users can view and edit their own profile, then another admin/users_controller.rb fully intended for staff user editing in an administrative backend. Because you don't want registerable, you could probably just do the one users_controller.rb and put your full CRUD/REST/etc in there, yes.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me.

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:password)
      params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
...
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
...
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
resources :users
...
```

I hope this can help you.

Regards,
Giacomo