# Devise CanCan Roles and Profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, user-profile

I am trying to create profile pages for my community site.  I have followed video tutorials and read docs on github for both Devise gem and CanCan gem. I have installed and currently have a functioning authentication system thanks to these two gems and the tutorials at railscasts.

I am very new to ruby and rails so everything is still very literal.  My first question relates to a line of code from CanCan [wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) page

```
<!-- in users/_form.html.erb -->
<%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize %>
```

I do not see a users folder or this controller.  Is this something I can generate - for example I ran

```
rails g devise User
```

Could I also run:

```
rails g controller Users
```

I have seen this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721276/rails-3-devise-gem-how-to-manage-users-through-crud-interface) but do not quite understand the answer.  Will I get an error by generating the "Users" controller to handle the things I would like to do?

I generated the devise views, but don't see any controllers - I understand that these could be overwritten - although I dont quite understand how this would work.  If I overwrite than would all default devise controller functionality still work plus overwritten controller?

If I can generate the "Users" controller, I assume I could just put a view template into that location for all of the profile view information.  I apologize for the amount of questions and length of this post, but I think with a little help I could be off and running again.  Thanks for any information provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so I solved this!  I will post my solution for anyone with a similar question who could potentially benefit.

One of my questions was:

> Could I also run:
>
> ```
> rails g controller Users
> ```

Yes this is what I did.  I use [nifty scaffold](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators) generators to generate the views so this command would actually look like the following

```
rails g nifty:scaffold user
```

It is important to note that I DID NOT pass any variables after user.  Devise has already created Users table in the database. This would create a conflict. Rails thinks you would like to overwrite your original database - which you do not want to do.

Do this builds the correct structure for User CRUD. Next open your config/routes.rb file.
Using nifty generators add the `resources :users` to the top of this file - move this below the devise resource and prefix the path as described on [this devise wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface) to resemble the code below.

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
resources :users
```

This is very important to remove any conflicts with your User controller and the devise controllers  url paths by adding the "/d/" prefix to all devise controllers.

As well as adding the following code to you users_controller update method:

```
if params[:user][:password].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:password)
  params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
end
```

Which ensures devise will validate correctly.

Now comes the fun - register a user if you have not done so already.  You now have a profile page for that user located at:

localhost:3000/users/1
localhost:3000/users/2
localhost:3000/users/3
...ect

You can edit user show.html.erb page in the views folder to change what information will display on each users profile page.

As for my question about Roles:

```
<!-- in users/_form.html.erb -->
<%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize %>
```

You now have access to this in the user controllers created by nifty-scaffold generator, so you can add this code to your form if you were also following Ryan Bates methods to integrate CanCan roles as described [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization).

Hopefully this help some else.